# Query está retornando um array vazio (MySQL/Wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, wordpress, select

Como faço para pegar os valores do campo `meta_value` = `candidate` dessa tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando essa query, mas esta retornando um array vazio.

```
$resultados2 = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value = 'candidate';");

print_r($resultados2);
```

Eu quero recuperar os campos `candidate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OPERADOR LIKE**

O array está sendo retornado vazio porque você está procurando por 'candidate' (exatamente) e na verdade o registro vem como "a:1:{s:9:"candidate";b:1;}". O LIKE fará uma busca aproximada e retornará os registros quem contém "candidate".

Simplesmente muda tua consulta da seguinte forma:

```
$wpdb->usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%candidate%'
```

Os `%` são wildcards (coringas) que permitem que qualquer valor antes ou depois do termo procurado seja aceito. Você poderia usar `%` apenas antes e apenas depois do valor, mas no seu caso é necessário usar os dois.

Comment: Completando a resposta... O array está sendo retornado vazio porque você está procurando por 'candidate' (exatamente) e na verdade o registro vem como "a:1:{s:9:"candidate";b:1;}". O LIKE fará uma busca aproximada e retornará os registros quem contém "candidate".

Comment: @JefersonLeonardo tomei a liberdade de incrementar a resposta com tua sugestão, ok?

Comment: Ok, @Thiago Santos